# Add items to list using while

Tags: python, list, while-loop, count, append

i want to add items to a list and count them. and calculate who has won the election. I can't get it to work. maybe someone can help me? i am new to python.

```
mylist = []
while vote == "Dominique":
cast_vote = input("who do you want to vote for?")
mylist.append(cast_vote)
if vote== "dominique":
    cast_vote = input("who do you want to vote for?")
    mylist.append(cast_vote)
elif stem == "Zacharia":
    cast_vote = input("who do you want to vote for?")
    mylist.append(cast_vote)
elif stem == "zacharia":
    cast_vote = input("who do you want to vote for?")
    mylist.append(cast_vote)
else:
    a = mylist.count("Dominique")
    b = mylist.count("dominique")
    c = mylist.count("Zacharia")
    d = mylist.count("zacharia")
    if a+b > c+d: 
        print("Dominique wonn!")
    else:
        print("Zacharia wonn!")
```

Comment: I think there is an indentation error in the code you have posted.  Check your code runs and carefully read any error messages to see if they help you fix it before posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic & code was wrong:

```
mylist = []
while True:
    cast_vote = input("who do you want to vote for?\n")
    mylist.append(cast_vote.lower())
    if("over" == cast_vote):
        break
a = mylist.count("dominique")
b = mylist.count("zacharia")
if a > b: 
    print("Dominique wonn!")
elif a==b:
    print("Election Tie")
else:
    print("Zacharia wonn!")
```

when election is over just type "over" instead of representative name.